# Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- v8 on Linux

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, gemfile

Trying to upgrade Rails from 5.2.0 to 5.2.3 is showing harder than I thought. I am facing a `Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- v8` during application start up.

If replace `mini_racer` by `therubyracer` the app starts up but it will throw `ExecJS::RubyRacerRuntime is not supported. Please replace therubyracer with mini_racer in your Gemfile or use Node.js as ExecJS runtime.`

I have `nodejs` installed and my `Gemfile` is the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '> 5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rack-attack', '~> 5.4.2'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'less-rails-semantic_ui'

gem 'libv8'
gem 'mini_racer'

gem 'faraday'
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1.6'
gem 'retriable'
gem 'stripe'

# gem 'prometheus_exporter'
gem 'prometheus-client'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Debug on RubyMine
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.7.0.beta4'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rack-test'
end
```

Is it me or the JS runtime environment seems really messy to get it right. Plenty of questions everywhere with people getting the right combination of versions that make things work without really knowing what is going on.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that the application loaded fine; then the **only** (???) thing you changed was upgrading rails, then you got the above error? I ask because if you inadvertently upgraded a dozen other things, it could be very hard for us to help diagnose the problem. Can you perhaps show a *minimal* `Gemfile.lock` diff which introduces the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is only a try:

1. gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'  change into gem "web-console"
2. gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0' change into gem 'spring-watcher-listen'
3. gem "mini_racer", platforms: :ruby`